# Time-based instead of frame-based zones (with different CRF) for ffmpeg+x264/x265 encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, x264, x265

[x264/5 have a `zones` parameter](https://x265.readthedocs.io/en/master/cli.html#quality-rate-control-and-rate-distortion-options) to support different encode settings for part of a video, but it only accepts frame numbers, not timestamps.

This is a minor inconvenience with constant-frame-rate video, but a major inconvenience when using an ffmpeg filter like `mpdecimate` to drop (almost) exact duplicate frames.  Or with VFR video in general.  (And if it doesn't work with `ffmpeg`, only an option to the stand-alone CLI, that would also be a major inconvenience.)

---

libx265 (and libx264) have an API that allows the caller to reconfigure some encoder parameters on the fly, so ffmpeg's libx264 and libx265 encoder wrappers *could* in theory adjust the CRF or other encoder parameters in a certain range of timestamps, separately from x264's own "zones" feature.

ffmpeg does have start/stop ranges for filters, so its command-line / option parsing probably has most of the code needed to handle this.

But AFAIK, this is not currently implemented.  `ffmpeg -h encoder=libx265` doesn't shows anything relevant; `-x265-params` is parsed to config the encoder once at startup and there are only a couple other options supported.  (`libx264` has many more ffmpeg options, but not any kind of zones that I can see.)

---

**Is there some alternative way to encode with `-vf mpdecimate` (or an arbitrary VFR source) and have CRF30 for most of the video, but CRF=24 from `00:30:00` to `00:30:30`, for example?**

In my case, there's one visually interesting clip that's worth spending extra bits on quality, and I'd rather not chop the video up and use [MKV ordered chapters](https://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?p=1138024#post1138024) just to make this happen.  Although if there's some straightforward `ffmpeg` syntax to do that (especially in one pass), that would be nice.  Something that can reasonably fit in a bash shell "one liner" is what I'm aiming for.

To do this with zones, I think I'd need to run the video through `mpdecimate` and find out the frame numbers of the start/end of that time region.  And I think I'd need to run the video through the stand-alone `x265` CLI, because I think zones are a feature of the command-line front-end, not the library itself. (And thus not supported via `-x265-params` to pass key/value pairs to libx265).

I checked to see if Handbrake supported any kind of zones, and I don't see it in the GUI.  (And Arch Linux's Handbrake 1.0.7 package is still using x265 2.1, so it doesn't even have the updated Lambda tables from [x265 2.4](http://x265.readthedocs.io/en/default/releasenotes.html#version-2-4), which came out over 9 months ago.  Handbrake is nice except for having outdated private copies of codecs instead of building against the system version, which definitely still matters for x265.)

Comment: x265-params **will** set zones.

Comment: @Mulvya: ok thanks, so that takes care of CFR content with ffmpeg.  But the question of VFR content still stands; time -> frame number is complicated in that case.

Comment: You'll need two passes. Apply mpdecimate and then showinfo. Note the `n` for the start/end pts_times. Then encode in 2nd pass.